# Concatenate (glue) where conditions by OR or AND (Arel, Rails3)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, subquery, where-clause, arel

I have several **complex** queries (using subqueries, etc...) and want to glue them together with OR or AND statement.

For example:

```
where1=table.where(...)
where2=table.where(...)
```

I would like something like

```
where3=where1.or where2
```

Next example doesn't work for me:

```
users.where(users[:name].eq('bob').or(users[:age].lt(25)))
```

because of I have several where(..) queries and I want to concatenate *them*.

**In other words**

I have 3 methods: first return first where, second-second, third - OR concatenation.

I must have able to use *all 3 methods* in my application and save **DRY** code

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for the form:

```
users.where(users[:name].eq('bob').or(users[:age].lt(25)))
```

docs: https://github.com/rails/arel

Answer (score 1):

users.where(users[:name].eq('bob').or(users[:age].lt(25))) is close, but you need to get the arel_table to specify the columns, e.g.

```
t = User.arel_table
User.where(t[:name].eq('bob').or(t[:age].lt(25)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that for AND concatenation you can do:

```
users = User.where(:name => 'jack')
users = users.where(:job => 'developer')
```

and you get a concatenation with AND in SQL (try it with `#to_sql` at the end)

Other than that you can do:

```
where1=table.where(...)
where2=table.where(...)
where1 & where2
```

example:

```
(User.where(:name => 'jack') & User.where(:job => 'dev')).to_sql
=> "SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`name` = 'jack' AND `users`.`job` = 'dev'"
```