# Two arrays of conditions in single ActiveRecord 'where' clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

Let's say I have two pairs of SQL conditions like these:

```
a = [ "users.accepted = ? AND users.active_at > ?", true,  Time.zone.now ]
b = [ "users.accepted = ? AND users.active_at > ?", false, Time.zone.now + 3.days ]
```

I can use code like `User.where(a)` to get all rows that satisfy the `a` condition. How can I use `where` to get rows that satisfy either `a` or `b` conditions? The result should be `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112186/concatenate-glue-where-conditions-by-or-or-and-arel-rails3

Comment: The result should be ActiveRecord::Relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to go about this.

1. get [meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where) or [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) depending upon your rails version. These are really great gems that enhance the Arel behavior of ActiveRecord::Relation.
2. write sql manually and pass it into the where method as a string. You might have to mess with sql injection more manually, but from your example above I didn't see any incoming values that were user generated strings.

Comment: +1 for squeel, did not try it yet but it looks plain, bold, capitalized **AWESOME**

Comment: Thanks. I did it using combined SQL query but that looks like there should be a way to do that using 'where' method.